# CKeditor and Chrome 29: Uncaught typeerror

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ckeditor

I am trying to use CK editor 4.2 in my project. But i have hit a strange error.

When opening a page with ckeditor in chrome, it just doesn't work. I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

It works fine under firefox or IE8, but not chrome. Hell, it doesn't even work on their official site. And i tried to delete my cache, disabling cache in dev-tools.

Did anybody else encounter this strange behaviour?

Comment: Provide a Fiddle. I'm unable to reproduce. You can also submit it to the [official bug tracker](https://dev.ckeditor.com/wiki/Bugs).

Comment: Examples from their site seem to work fine in Chrome 29.0.1547.62 here.

Comment: That is the problem, how can the example not work for me... but the example in the zip file is working without problems